# Equivalent of mvn dependency:tree in Grails

Tags: grails, maven, ivy

I am trying to find out some dependencies added to a grails plugin that I am using in my grails project. Is there any equivalent of maven command `mvn dependency:tree` in Grails/Ivy

Answer (score 46, accepted):

How about `grails dependency-report` ([docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/dependency-report.html))